# How to get from Vienna airport (VIE) to Bratislava airport (BTS)?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, bratislava, vie

Vienna airport (VIE) and Bratislava airport (BTS) are very close but in different countries. Googling I've found how to get from VIE to Vienna city center, then to Bratislava and finally get to BTS airport, but I can't find any direct way to join the airports.

Is there any way to connect them? If not, how long does it require to get from one airport to the other?

Comment: [Ryanair has a bus from Vienna center to BTS](http://ryanair.plusairportline.com/index.php?page=destinations&id=57) which is at least one step less but it's sync'd to Ryanair flights.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two companies running a direct bus connection between the airports.

1. [Flixbus](https://www.flixbus.com/). Their bus #910 runs [once per hour](http://www.viennaairport.com/jart/prj3/va/uploads/data-uploads/Passagier/Parken/VIE_Eurolines_7010_de_en.pdf) and takes 60 minutes. A single ticket costs 5`EUR` (or 7.5`EUR`, depending on the time), pre-bookable on their website.
2. [Postbus](http://www.postbus.at/en/). Their bus #1195 runs [once every two hours](http://www.viennaairport.com/jart/prj3/va/uploads/data-uploads/Passagier/Parken/VIE_Postbus_1195_de_en.pdf) and takes 75 minutes. A single ticket costs 8`EUR`, with no reservations available online.

As an alternative you could [take a taxi](https://www.bratislava-airport-taxi.com/) from one airport to the other for about 60`EUR`. The journey should take around 40 minutes, depending on the traffic.

[FlyNiki](https://www.flyniki.com/en/) used to run a [direct flight](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2901784/Introducing-world-s-shortest-international-flight-Airline-launch-TEN-MINUTE-route-Vienna-Bratislava-worth-airport-queues.html) between the two airports, taking 10 minutes and costing 40`EUR`, but unfortunately it's no longer available.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it __unfortunately__. Having a 10 minute flight seems like the most useless environmental pollution ever, given that including boarding time one can only be faster by some minutes.

Comment: @dirkk the reason that flight existed was because they needed to move planes from one city to the other once a week. So they would fly it regardless of how many passengers were on board. Zero impact from buying an extra ticket.

Comment: There is also Slovaklines which offers connection between VIE (also Center) & BTS  https://www.slovaklines.sk/main-page.html

Answer (score 7):

In case you are reading this in 2020, just take the [hyperloop](https://www.engadget.com/2016/03/10/hyperloop-transportation-technologies-slovakia-contract/) :)

> One of the companies vying to make Elon Musk's transportation dream a reality has signed a deal with the government of Slovakia to explore building a three-country Hyperloop. Crowdsourced engineering project Hyperloop Transportation Technologies (HTT) will look into a route that links three European capitals. From Vienna, Austria to Bratislava, Slovakia, and from Bratislava to Budapest, Hungary.
>
> While the idea of a three-country Hyperloop might seem extreme, the distances between the three cities is actually fairly trivial. Vienna to Bratislava is a 35-mile straight line, or 50 miles by current transport routes. Bratislava to Budapest is a 100-mile straight line, or 125 miles by transport. Both are well within the realm of possibility.